# Not able to get access token from azure AD using MSAL4J

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to access graph api. I'm using `MSAL4J` to access the `graph` apis. But I'm getting `com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` even when I'm not using my vpn.

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/console-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-java) tutorial. I've followed all the steps mentioned in there.

Here the stack trace:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) at ClientCredentialGrant.getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant(ClientCredentialGrant.java:78) at ClientCredentialGrant.main(ClientCredentialGrant.java:36) Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:53) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.executeRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:218) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.sendInstanceDiscoveryRequest(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:172) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.doInstanceDiscoveryAndCache(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:271) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.getMetadataEntry(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:56) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.getAuthorityWithPrefNetworkHost(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:32) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:59) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.acquireTokenByClientCredential(AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.java:63) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByClientCredentialSupplier.java:49) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673) at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474) at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.readResponseFromConnection(DefaultHttpClient.java:107) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.executeHttpGet(DefaultHttpClient.java:47) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.DefaultHttpClient.send(DefaultHttpClient.java:35) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequestWithRetries(HttpHelper.java:96) at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpRequest(HttpHelper.java:49) ... 16 more`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. And writing this answer with hope that it will help someone. `com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` This exception was occurring due to the proxy issues.

My system was behind the proxy so it was not able to connect with `microsoftonline` servers.

I have two approaches to get the `access_token` from `azure AD`.

**First Approach**
Using `REST API` provided by `AZURE AD`

```
public String getAccessToken() throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("your_proxy_address", your_proxy_port));
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(proxy).build();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
                "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=your_client_id&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret=your_client_secret",
                mediaType);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://login.microsoftonline.com/your tenent id/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                .method("POST", body).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        // String token = response.body().string();
        return mapper.readTree(response.body().string()).get("access_token").asText();
    }
```

You can get the `access_token` by using this method. Another approach is, by using the `MSAL4J` library.
**Second approach**

First build client `object`

```
private static void BuildConfidentialClientObject() throws Exception {

        Proxy proxy = AuthProvider.getInstance().getProxy();

        app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(secret))
                .proxy(proxy).authority(authority).build();
    }
```

Then get the `access_token`

```
private static IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant() throws Exception {

        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters
                .builder(Collections.singleton(scope)).build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
        return future.join();

    }
```

Now you can access the `graph APIs` using this `access_token` and complete your tasks.

**PS:** I'm using `demon` approach for my tasks. There are different approaches to fulfill your requirements.

You can have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) for authentication approach reference.